# Workaround for pinnable Office add-in on OS X?

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-web-addins, outlook-for-mac

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/pinnable-taskpane), I know that pinnable task panes are only available for Windows and Outlook Online. Is there any kind of workaround for pinnable task panes on OS X?  If I modify the manifest to include pinning, Outlook for Mac sporadically crashes with bug messages like:

> Exception: EXC_BAD_ACCESS
>
> Exception Code: KERN_NAME_EXISTS (0x00007f86cd511698)

I assume this is because some objects are zombies when a pinned email message is changed. Is there any hope besides waiting for Microsoft to support pinning on OS X add-ins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/pinnable-taskpane) is updated and Outlook for Mac supports pinnable task pane starting from 16.13.503 version.

> Pinnable task panes are currently available to Office 365 subscribers on Outlook 2016 or later for Windows (build 7668.2000 or later for users in the Current or Office Insider Channels, build 7900.xxxx or later for users in Deferred channels), Outlook 2016 or later for Mac (version 16.13.503 or later), and Outlook Online.